# "we'll use" or "we'll be using"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I am learning [this](https://youtu.be/87vSKxEi2pM?t=24) HarvardX course.

The professor is saying

> Note that the data set we will be using, included in the Lahman
>   Library

don't be bothered by the term "Lahman Library", which is just a series of record about baseball statistics.

The question is, does "we will be using" express more info than "we'll use"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "we will be using" is the future continuous tense, which refers to something that will continue in future for an expected time. As an example "I will be travelling to London tomorrow" describes an action that will continue for an expected time.

On the other hand "we'll use" is future tense which is more appropriate for an event that will happen in future. As an example you can say "I will arrive in London at 5.00 AM tomorrow".

So in your case I think "we will be using" sounds more appropriate.